# MySQL group by selecting the result for group by primary key not ordered subquery result

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-5.7

In one of my legacy application, there is a query to fetch the first row for each group i.e.,

```
SELECT
    columnPrimaryKey,
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column4
FROM
    (SELECT
        columnPrimaryKey,
        column1,
        column2,
        column3,
        column4
    FROM tableName
    ORDER BY column4
) AS tbl
GROUP BY column3
```

The above query is not returning the first( ordered by column4 ) row, instead returning the first row by the primary key column i.e., `columnPrimaryKey`.

This used to work earlier. I recall we had a mysql upgrade and the current version is `5.7.22-log`.

I can rewrite the query as following and it will work as expected:

```
SELECT
    x.columnPrimaryKey,
    x.column1,
    x.column2,
    x.column3,
    x.column4
FROM tableName AS x INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        MIN( column4 ) AS column4,
        column3
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY column3
) AS y ON x.column4 = y.column4 AND x.column3 = y.column3;
```

I have checked the `sql_mode` as it's `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

Can anyone point out why the first query is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The first query's select list:

```
SELECT
    columnPrimaryKey,
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column4
```

is unclear, because you are running the query in `GROUP BY` aggregation mode, grouping by `column3`.  This means that only a single record would be reported for each value of `column3`.  In the event that there are more than one record for a given value of `column3`, you have not told MySQL *which* value you want to report for the other columns.  Therefore, in principle, MySQL is free to go off and choose any of those values which it wants.  Exactly why this is happening is not so important as that you keep using your second, correct, approach moving forward.

So in general, you should keep in mind that when you group by one or more columns, the only columns you may select are the columns appearing in `GROUP BY`, *or* any other column, so long as it appears inside an *aggregate* function.

Comment: @Beginner Are you asking me a question?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is expected. Especially if you have upgraded from <= 5.7.5. MySQL has turned "**only full group by**" mode on as default. `SideNote:`It is always advisable to check their "change list" before upgrading to a newer version.

MySQL says.

> ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
>
> Reject queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER
>   BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the
>   GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined
>   by) GROUP BY columns.

More here.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: The `@@sql_mode` is only returning `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` so, is the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` still on?

Comment: @Beginner I believe so since it's default (preferred). If you wish, you can try sql_mode="TRADITIONAL"

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comments, adding here for reference:

From MySQL docs:

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If
>   the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default),
>   MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in
>   the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before
>   5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. )
>
> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard
>   SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns
>   are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL
>   to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to
>   choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the
>   values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you
>   want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs
>   after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which
>   value within each group the server chooses. Disabling
>   ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is useful primarily when you know that, due to some
>   property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated column not
>   named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.

More can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html